# Problem with getting a list as an aswer in pyswip

Tags: python, prolog

I've just started tinkering with `Pyswip` trying to integrate a Prolog knowledge base into a Python program. It seemed to work smoothly until I tried to get the value of a list. Just to give an example of the problem:

```
In [1]: from pyswip import Prolog

In [2]: p = Prolog()

In [3]: p.assertz("father(andrew, [burt, carol])")

In [4]: sol = p.query("father(andrew, X)")

In [5]: a = next(sol)

In [6]: a

Out[6]: {'X': [Atom('441093'), Atom('441221')]}
```

Any ideas about how to get a real answer?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've hit [Issue #16](https://github.com/yuce/pyswip/issues/16), updating to the latest version of PySWIP with Python3 should fix it *(there's still [some mutterings](https://github.com/yuce/pyswip/issues/46) about it occurring with Python2)*.

Comment: I was aware of Issue#16. The problem remains because: (a) it was produced by using PySwip version 0.2.8 with Python 3.7.2; (b) the link suggested by the author ("This is fixed in the rewrite/refactoring of PySwip in the refactor branch. E.g.,: https://github.com/yuce/pyswip/blob/refactor/tests/test_prolog.py") is broken.  So I walk in the dark, and it is a pity because PySwip seems an interesting tool.

Comment: Argh, that's a shame, I was hoping it was going to be an easy fix for you. PySWIP is undergoing a big refactor, if you raise the issue there they might be able to fix it. In the meantime, could [SWI-Prolog Pengines](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(%27packages/pengines.html%27)) and [PythonPengines](https://github.com/ian-andrich/PythonPengines) provide an alternative solution for you?

Comment: I must confess that I did not know about the existence of Python Pengines and that I've never paid too much attention to the SWI library: I classified it exclusively as Prolog web tool. 

Now I think it's time to investigate whether and how they could work in my project. In any case, thank you for your time and suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The string content is actually contained in the Atom objects, the only issue is that the necessary automatic conversion to Python strings is not always performed. In such cases you can perform the conversion manually.

For example, when printing a list the conversion is not performed, but when printing a single element the string content is shown:

```py
from pyswip import Prolog

p = Prolog()
p.assertz("father(andrew, [burt, carol])")

sol = p.query("father(andrew, X)")
a = next(sol)
print(a)
# {'X': [Atom('392453'), Atom('392581')]}
print(a['X'][1])
# carol
```

Finding a substring with `in` needs manual conversion:

```
name = a['X'][1]
if "aro" in name: # TypeError: argument of type 'Atom' is not iterable
if "aro" in str(name): # ok
```

Converting the full result dictionary for the example code:

```
a = {variable: [str(elem) for elem in a[variable]] for variable in a}
print(a)
# {'X': ['burt', 'carol']}
```